# Weird behavior of repeated Mod of Hash

Tags: modular-arithmetic, hashing

I was working on a [wolfram challenge](https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/challenge/hash-loop) problem involving `Hash`, and I noticed some very odd behavior. The problem is to create a function `HashLoop` to find the first repeated number when repetitively taking the hash mod 65536.

I will not post my code for the challenge (because that defeats the purpose of the challenge), but I know it's correct. Looking at i=0 to 1000, we see the vast majority of inputs' first repeating number is 1753...why is this?

```
Tally@Table[HashLoop[i], {i, 0, 1000}]
(*{{1753, 899},...}*)
```

I feel like this sort of predictability is not something you want with `Hash` but maybe it doesn't matter?

My `$Version` is `13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)`

*Add-on*
I changed my mind, just for clarity, this is the code for `HashLoop`. Please don't look at it if you want to do the challenges in the future. They are fun.

> `HashLoop[n_Integer]/;0 ≤ n ≤ 65535 := NestWhile[Mod[Hash[#], 65536] &, n, UnsameQ, All]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _predictability_? Perhaps it is instructive to look at a smaller example (e.g. mod 25): `Graph[Table[i \[DirectedEdge] Mod[Hash[i], 25], {i, 0, 24}], VertexLabels -> Automatic]`. As you see, there are only three stationary points: 22, 8 and 16. However, the proportions of numbers that result in each of them is very different (only 1 number leads to 16, 6 numbers lead to 22 and 18 lead to 8). When you hash higher numbers, they are _equally_ (!) spread (`Histogram[Table[Mod[Hash[i], 25], {i, 100000}]]`).

Comment: So the resulting tally completely depends only on the relationship between 25 numbers (or in your case, 65536).

Comment: I mean predictability in the sense that a vast majority of numbers end up showing 1753 as the first repeated number, even though we apply `Hash` at every step. Shouldn't it be evenly spread across the range 0-65536? 

When I hash higher numbers, it's the same:

`rI = RandomInteger[{10^6, 10^7}, 50];`

`Tally[HashLoop /@ rI]`

`(*{{1753, 43},...}*)`

Comment: Also I am not sure what the meaning of the stationary points 22, 8 and 16 is in the graph. Changing 65536 to 25 in my code yields:

`(HashLoop25 /@ Range[0, 24]) // Tally`
`(*{{2, 7}, {17, 6}, {4, 1}, {7, 2}, {23, 4}, {12, 1}, {13, 1}, {15, 
  1}, {18, 1}, {21, 1}}*)`

Comment: ^ I hope I did not come across as rude above, I probably just don't know enough about graphs

Comment: The graph shows how each number is mapped to another number by "your" function, `x |-> Mod[Hash[x], 25]`. You can pick a number, and follow the arrows. At some point, you will encounter a cycle – numbers will start to repeat themselves. But as you can see, this repetition cannot happen at any number, but only at numbers 22, 8 and 16 (which I called "stationary points").

Comment: When starting with a large number, after first iteration, it will be mapped to one of these 25 numbers (with rather equal probability!). Then, it will follow the arrows, and the repetition will happen exactly at one of those three numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148347/discussion-between-ydd-and-domen).